# How to deliver the parameter between two panels?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

As we all know, I have an A panel and B panel, when some value setting in the A, i must update the same value into the B panel field.

in the A panel:

```
fireEvent('RFtemperatureChange', measure);
```

after the event been fire. I set a listener in their parent panel, when it listen the event, it will always fireEvent to B panel.

```
this.on('RFtemperatureChange', this.synchronizedWithReferTemprature, this);

synchronizedWithReferTemprature : function(measure){
    console.log('pre');
  //here to fireEvent the B panel
  },
```

In the B panel:

```
this.on('RFtemperatureInputChange', this.synchronizedWithReferTemprature, this);
```

Comment: What about working with the selection? `gridA.getSelectionModel().getSelection()` (or something like this)

Comment: @Tarabass please don't create new tags for minor version revisions of software; only major differences between versions merit new tags.